# SSIS Data Flow out of synchronization doesn't make sense

Tags: ssis, synchronization, dataflow

I have a data flow from an Excel sheet with these inputs:
[image]

going to a database table that look like this:
[image]

But I get an error stating:
The external columns for Registrations_by_Tracker_Codes_ are out of synchronization with the data source columns.
The column "date" needs to be added to the external columns.
The Registrations_by_Tracker_Codes_.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[Registration Date] needs to be removed from the external columns.

This does not make sense because "date" already exists in the External columns and "Registration Date" does not exist in the External columns.
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I discovered my problem. The file that I was using to define the Input Cols was not exactly like the actual data files. Thanks to all who read and considered my question!